# VideoView doesn't play for 60 seconds in S9

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, samsung-galaxy

I am facing with one issue with Samsung Galaxy S9.

I stored one video file in project resource/raw, and app play video with VideoView.

Here is my code.

```
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_sample_google;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {               
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```

Above code works well with S8, but not working with S9.
If the video duration is less than a certain time (in my testing, it was 45 to 50 seconds), video plays well in S9.

But the video duration is longer than certain time, the VideoView doesn't play for  60 seconds exactly.
For example, if the video duration is 55 secs, 60 secs, 70 secs, ... video is played after a min exactly.

Please help me to fix this issue or another way to play video (duration should longer than a min, and the video is always local, and with S9)

Comment: what is the container file type `mov`, `mp4` etc .. what is the encoding `H.264`, `HEVC`? What is the native video dimensions `240p`, `480p` etc. Have you confirmed that the used codecs used are hardware or software decoded, and if so different between models? Unfortunately the supplied generic code is too high level to provide any meaningful solutions.

Comment: @MarkKeen video is mp4, and 720dp. even I tried to download sample mp4 from google but same result. as I said short video works well in S9, but longer video doesn't works.

One things, video works well with S9 default Video Player